# Is Hizdahr responsible?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In episode 5.9, when the Great Games are about to begin, Hizdahr comes in late and says that he was "making sure everything is in order" for the games.

Later in the scene,

> The Sons of the Harpy attack Daenerys and the crowd, and Hizdahr is stabbed to death in the conflict.

Although he clearly would not have wanted the events to play out the way they did, is Hizdahr responsible for the events that transpired in the colloseum?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would appear to be too likely a coincidence indeed. From the books, it would appear that Hizdar was complicit in the plans of the Sons of the Harpy. His notable absence for one at the start of 5.9.

In the books, it transpires that once Daenerys marries Hizdar, the killings cease, leading many to believe it was a strategic move of Hizdar's to marry Daenerys, and use his power to control the Sons of the Harpy as a bargaining chip.

However there is no certain proof in either the TV series or the books, that Hizdar is certainly the culprit. What I guess we are lead to believe is that he may have some role in destabilizing Daenerys' rule.

Comment: In the books, I have no doubt Hizdar is in league with the Sons of the Harpy. In the TV show, however, I have my doubts... it's clearly not a power play to marry Daenerys, since he doesn't propose this and instead it's Dany's own idea. In fact, she comes very close to murdering Hizdar! I'd say he belonged to the noble caste and therefore had lots in common with the Sons, but he wasn't controlling them. Also, they murder him, and his death doesn't look like an accident.

Comment: Excellent point. The book is quite different in its approach to the power struggles of Meereen. There were several characters cut from the book in the TV show, and the way in which Hizdahr dies is divergent too from the book's narrative. It will be interesting to see how the Dany disappearance plays out in meereen. I suspect Tyrion and Jorah may find things difficult.

Comment: @AndresF. If in the books, Hizdahr is in league while in the show, Hizdahr is not in league, does that mean whether or not Hizdahr is in league doesn't affect the story much?

Comment: Mothermole1, what is the coincidence? Hizdahr taking part in the events at Colosseum or not?

Comment: @BCLC Exactly, I'd say it's not very important for the plot.